# Why is the discrete exponential map not injective once a path reaches a saddle vertex?

Tags: differential-geometry, discrete-geometry

I'm reading the following survey on algorithms for computing geodesic paths on discretized surfaces: [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/GeodesicSurvey/GeodesicSurvey.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/GeodesicSurvey/GeodesicSurvey.pdf)

According to the authors, on the following diagram (on page 11 of the pdf) we can see paths from an arbitrary vertex $i$ to vertices $j$, a vertex of positive angle defect (think of angle defect as the discrete version of gaussian curvature), and $k$ a vertex of negative angle defect:

[image]

It's very clear to me why the exponential map fails to be injective when moving close to vertex $i$, the authors even describe themselves than the green and red paths converge on the other side (the boundary edges adjacent to $j$ in the diagram are glued together when this surface is embedded in $\mathbb R^3$)

However I'm struggling to understand why they claim that the exponential map fails to be injective when rays pass close to vertex $k$. They seem to split up and not converge later so I don't see why it can't be injective

Comment: I think the issue is that we cannot see clearly in this figure how the angle defect at $k$ is negative; what is happening behind?

Comment: The angle defect is $2\pi$ - (the sum of all angles at the vertex). Since the angles cover more than a full rotation, the angle defect there is negative

Comment: @TedShifrin this is a "planar" view of the discretized surface. Imagine a mooth surface - with nonnegative gaussian curvature you can flatten the surface onto a plane by making a cut, but that's not possible with negative curvature - you get an overlap (which is the overlap seen in the image)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. So doesn't the overlap cause non-injectivity just as the identification of edges does in the positive curvature case?

Comment: @TedShifrin maybe? It's not so obvious to me why. Which rays end up converging with other rays?

Comment: This is a triangulation of a surface with no boundary. Where does that "free" edge emanating from $k$ get attached?

Comment: @TedShifrin I just updated the image. The edges painted blue adjacent to k are the ones that are supposed to be glued together

Comment: So then the rays going to those edges will meet, just as they did in the positive curvature case.

Comment: @TedShifrin but unless I'm visualizing it really wrong, no rays emanating from $i$ touch those edges, except at the vertex $k$

Comment: Yeah, that's not correct. The space is geodesically complete.

Comment: Like, the green rays pass "under" the triangle with the blue edge on the left, and similarly the red rays fly "over" the triangle with the other blue edge

Comment: You need to draw the geodesics from $i$ to points on those blue edges. The picture is not an accurate representation of the saddle behavior of the actual surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. I'll try drawing those then. Thank you!